# SQL: Arithmetic operations on aggregate functions in a select statement shows wrong information

Tags: mysql, sql-server, parallel-data-warehouse

I am working on a query for collecting some data on Microsoft Parallel data warehouse(PDW).

A part of the query is as follows --

```
Select

min(rows) as rows_min,

max(rows) as rows_max,

sum(rows) as rows_total,

cast((((max(rows)-min(rows))/sum(rows))*100) as float) as SkewPct;

from .....;
```

Apparently query doesn't show any error. It runs successfully but with correct data in all columns except SkewPct which shows only zeros.

Please help me out to solve this issue!

Comment: MySQL or sql-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing multiplication of 1.0 during divide as below:

```
cast((((max(rows)-min(rows))/(sum(rows)*1.0))*100) as float) as SkewPct;
```

Divide removes the fraction before converting it into float

Answer (score 0):

As per MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert), `FLOAT` is not a valid type to use with `CAST`, you should use `DECIMAL` instead, with Maximum digits (M) and Decimal (D) as tw arguments:

> Produces a DECIMAL value. If the optional M and D values are given,
>   they specify the maximum number of digits (the precision) and the
>   number of digits following the decimal point (the scale).

By default, value will be rounded to `int` with 0 decimals. Have a look at the query below:

```
SELECT CAST((((127-23)/541)*100) as DECIMAL), CAST(19.2237 AS DECIMAL(7, 5))
```

First column results in `19` whereas second column results in `19.2237`.

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/766b8/27/0)**.